# iOS stringWithUTF8String (Really CFAllocatorAllocate) EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, under ARC

Tags: ios, nsstring, exc-bad-access

I have some code that seems as safe as I can make it...but I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  Not regularly mind, just this one time.

The code:

```
- (void) deviceListenerCallback:(DeviceEventTypeDef)type data:(void*)data
{
    DeviceInfoDef* o = (DeviceInfoDef*)data;
    char newName[256];
    if (o->DeviceName) {
        strncpy(newName, o->DeviceName, 255);
    } else {
        strncpy(newName, "(null)", 255);
    }
    NSString *deviceNameUTF8 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)newName];
```

'data' is a pointer passed to us from a C library.  The data is present, and uncorrupted.

The characters that end up in newName from the strncpy are "Network Audio\0\0\0\0\0..."

The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is on the last line when I'm calling stringWithUTF8String. the error is:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30303030)
```

The call stack is:

```
CFAllocatorAllocate
................................
5 +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]
6 -[MyClass deviceListenerCall...
```

The project is running under ARC.

Can anyone point out the newbie thing I must be doing wrong?

Thanks,

-Ken

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *deviceNameUTF8 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:newName length:255 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it would work.  However, I would have thought the code above would work as well.  Any ideas what is actually causing the problem?  Judging by the 0x30303030 address code, sounds to me like something is getting overwritten...but I can't guard against it unless I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you are using `strncpy()` at all given the input string contains the terminating `NUL`-character.

Why not simply create `deviceNameUTF8` (misnamed as that is not UTF-8) directly from `o->DeviceName`?

```
- (void) deviceListenerCallback:(DeviceEventTypeDef)type data:(void*)data
{
    DeviceInfoDef* o = (DeviceInfoDef*)data;
    NSString *deviceName;
    if (o != NULL)
        deviceName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:o->DeviceName];
    else
        deviceName = @"";
```

Comment: The reason for the strncpy is that o might be NULL. In the calling code there no guarantee that it's not, so an assert isn't going to be the right approach here.

Comment: @KenCorey Using `strncpy()` isn't going to help in the case where `o` is `NULL` either.  The correct approach therefore is to change the `NSAssert` to a `if (o != NULL)` test.  If `o` could be `NULL` then mentioning that might have helped answer your question.